# Flask 1.0.2 thread paused after request returns

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I have the following Issue:

ClientA -> request -> Flask Server -> spin up thread(no join) and return 200

Situation:

- When the request ends (returned 200), the thread is paused.
- when another request comes in, the thread is then resumed

`ie. 
I spin up a thread that checks the database for a user, then posts a message to slack. 
When the request returns, the thread never finishes executing, the message was never sent, until the next request comes in and somehow resumed the thread and then the message was sent to slack.`

Notes:

Shouldn't the thread run until the program exits? why is it being paused when the request returns and resumed when another request comes in.  The thread seems to not be running when flask is idle.

My code is as below:

```
def handle(self, data):
  # some operation that takes ~3secs
  # post message to slack
  return

def post(self):
  c = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(data, ))
  c.start()
  return "", 200
```

Enviroment:

Docker container

Comment: The thread ends when it reaches `return` or the implicit `return` at the end of the function.

Comment: any reason why it would then resume itself when a different request comes in? @KlausD.

Comment: It does not resume. A new thread is created.